# text behind Sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have the problem that as soon as I use an iPad / tablet and no PC, the content / text disappears behind the sidebar.

How can I make sure that the sidebar works as a “borderline” and that no text / content is displayed behind the sidebar?

I use bootstrap 5.

My html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
        <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'app_dashboard' %}
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                            <span data-feather="home"></span>
                            Test
                        </a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                            <span data-feather="home"></span>
                            Test
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    {% if app.request.get('_route') == '' %}
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file"></span>
                            Test
                        </a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file"></span>
                            Test
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <span data-feather="file-plus"></span>
                        Test
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <span data-feather="users"></span>
                        Test
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My own sidebar css:

```
    .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 45px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    width: 220px;
}

.sidebar .active {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

problem:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ie1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't split your sidebar and your content. You've basically just placed it onto your page without considering that the sidebar & content will be 2 different components. Since you're using Bootstrap I would recommend using [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/). Like this:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 45px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  width: 220px;
}

.sidebar .active {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 2px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
          <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                  <span data-feather="home"></span> Test
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard') }}">
                  <span data-feather="home"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file"></span> Test
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file-plus"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="users"></span> Test
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something else to note, for medium to smaller devices you will have to apply different styling's so this is where the power of bootstraps grid system will come in handy. [Grid Options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the sidebar is displayed when the screen is small. Actually, it should no longer be displayed. That was the correct case with my code.

Comment: For this, I guess you will have to use a hamburger menu

Comment: What do you mean, please? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: [Boostrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/), Check out this component by bootstrap and reduce your screen size. You can see a hamburger menu appears to hide the nav bar but still make it accessible for mobile users